# Installing Eclipse-cdt installs jdt and bunch of others as well

Tags: package-management, eclipse-cdt

I wanted to install eclipse-cdt for c++ development. But it looks like it cant be installed alone in ubuntu. Why are there separate packages if they can't be installed alone?

> [balakrishnan@mylap ~]$ sudo apt-get install eclipse-cdt Reading
>   package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state
>   information... Done The following extra packages will be installed:
>   ant ant-optional aspectj binfmt-support ca-certificates-java
>   default-jdk default-jre default-jre-headless eclipse-cdt-jni
>   eclipse-emf   **eclipse-jdt** **eclipse-pde** eclipse-platform
>   eclipse-platform-data **eclipse-rcp eclipse-rse** fastjar
>   icedtea-7-jre-jamvm jarwrapper java-common   junit junit4
>   libapache-pom-java libasm3-java libaspectj-java libatk-wrapper-java
>   libatk-wrapper-java-jni libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common
>   libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common libcommons-beanutils-java
>   libcommons-cli-java libcommons-codec-java libcommons-collections3-java
>   libcommons-compress-java libcommons-dbcp-java libcommons-digester-java
>   libcommons-httpclient-java libcommons-lang-java
>   libcommons-logging-java libcommons-parent-java libcommons-pool-java
>   libdb-java libdb-je-java libdb5.1-java libdb5.1-java-jni
>   libeasymock-java libecj-java libequinox-osgi-java
>   libfelix-bundlerepository-java libfelix-gogo-command-java
>   libfelix-gogo-runtime-java   libfelix-gogo-shell-java
>   libfelix-osgi-obr-java libfelix-shell-java libfelix-utils-java
>   libgconf2-4 libgeronimo-jpa-2.0-spec-java
>   libgeronimo-jta-1.1-spec-java libgeronimo-osgi-support-java libgif4
>   libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libgnomecanvas2-0
>   libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0
>   libgnomevfs2-common libhamcrest-java libice-dev libicu4j-4.4-java
>   libicu4j-java libidl-common libidl0 libjetty8-java libjline-java
>   libjsch-java libjtidy-java libkxml2-java liblucene2-java liborbit2
>   libosgi-compendium-java libosgi-core-java libosgi-foundation-ee-java
>   libpthread-stubs0 libpthread-stubs0-dev libregexp-java
>   libservlet2.5-java libservlet3.0-java libsm-dev libswt-cairo-gtk-3-jni
>   libswt-glx-gtk-3-jni libswt-gnome-gtk-3-jni libswt-gtk-3-java
>   libswt-gtk-3-jni libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni libtomcat7-java libx11-dev
>   libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libxerces2-java
>   libxml-commons-external-java libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java libxt-dev
>   libxz-java openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless
>   openjdk-7-jre-lib sat4j ttf-dejavu-extra tzdata-java x11proto-core-dev
>   x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
>   Suggested packages:   ant-gcj ant-doc libbsf-java liboro-java
>   libxalan2-java libjaxp1.3-java liblog4j1.2-java jython antlr
>   libbcel-java libjdepend-java   libgnumail-java libcommons-net-java
>   javacc ant-optional-gcj eclipse equivs junit-doc libbonobo2-bin
>   libcommons-beanutils-java-doc   libcommons-collections3-java-doc
>   libcommons-dbcp-java-doc libcommons-digester-java-doc
>   libcommons-httpclient-java-doc   libavalon-framework-java
>   libcommons-logging-java-doc libexcalibur-logkit-java libdb5.1-java-gcj
>   libeasymock-java-doc ecj libecj-java-gcj
>   libfelix-bundlerepository-java-doc libfelix-gogo-command-java-doc
>   libfelix-gogo-runtime-java-doc libfelix-gogo-shell-java-doc
>   libfelix-osgi-obr-java-doc libfelix-shell-java-doc
>   libfelix-utils-java-doc libgeronimo-jpa-2.0-spec-java-doc
>   libgeronimo-jta-java-doc   libgeronimo-osgi-support-java-doc
>   desktop-base libgnomevfs2-bin libgnomevfs2-extra gamin fam
>   gnome-mime-data libice-doc jetty8   libjetty8-java-doc
>   libjline-java-doc libjtidy-java-doc libosgi-compendium-java-doc
>   libosgi-core-java-doc libosgi-foundation-ee-java-doc   libsm-doc
>   libswt-gtk-3-java-gcj tomcat7 libxcb-doc libxerces2-java-doc
>   libxerces2-java-gcj libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java-doc libxt-doc
>   openjdk-7-demo openjdk-7-source visualvm icedtea-7-plugin
>   sun-java6-fonts fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho
>   ttf-telugu-fonts   ttf-oriya-fonts ttf-kannada-fonts ttf-bengali-fonts
>   The following NEW packages will be installed:   ant ant-optional
>   aspectj binfmt-support ca-certificates-java default-jdk default-jre
>   default-jre-headless eclipse-cdt eclipse-cdt-jni   eclipse-emf
>   eclipse-jdt eclipse-pde eclipse-platform eclipse-platform-data
>   eclipse-rcp eclipse-rse fastjar icedtea-7-jre-jamvm jarwrapper
>   java-common junit junit4 libapache-pom-java libasm3-java
>   libaspectj-java libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni
>   libbonobo2-0   libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common
>   libcommons-beanutils-java libcommons-cli-java libcommons-codec-java
>   libcommons-collections3-java libcommons-compress-java
>   libcommons-dbcp-java libcommons-digester-java
>   libcommons-httpclient-java   libcommons-lang-java
>   libcommons-logging-java libcommons-parent-java libcommons-pool-java
>   libdb-java libdb-je-java libdb5.1-java   libdb5.1-java-jni
>   libeasymock-java libecj-java libequinox-osgi-java
>   libfelix-bundlerepository-java libfelix-gogo-command-java
>   libfelix-gogo-runtime-java libfelix-gogo-shell-java
>   libfelix-osgi-obr-java libfelix-shell-java libfelix-utils-java
>   libgconf2-4   libgeronimo-jpa-2.0-spec-java
>   libgeronimo-jta-1.1-spec-java libgeronimo-osgi-support-java libgif4
>   libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common   libgnomecanvas2-0
>   libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0
>   libgnomevfs2-common libhamcrest-java libice-dev   libicu4j-4.4-java
>   libicu4j-java libidl-common libidl0 libjetty8-java libjline-java
>   libjsch-java libjtidy-java libkxml2-java liblucene2-java   liborbit2
>   libosgi-compendium-java libosgi-core-java libosgi-foundation-ee-java
>   libpthread-stubs0 libpthread-stubs0-dev libregexp-java
>   libservlet2.5-java libservlet3.0-java libsm-dev libswt-cairo-gtk-3-jni
>   libswt-glx-gtk-3-jni libswt-gnome-gtk-3-jni libswt-gtk-3-java
>   libswt-gtk-3-jni libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni libtomcat7-java libx11-dev
>   libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libxerces2-java
>   libxml-commons-external-java libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java libxt-dev
>   libxz-java openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless
>   openjdk-7-jre-lib sat4j ttf-dejavu-extra tzdata-java x11proto-core-dev
>   x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev 0
>   upgraded, 123 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. Need to
>   get 311 MB of archives. After this operation, 392 MB of additional
>   disk space will be used. Do you want to continue [Y/n]?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing eclipse from eclipse.org. Go to http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and download your preferred eclipse package. 
Then go to http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp?locale=en and download appropriate java version for your OS ("Linux" for i386 "Linux x64" for amd64). 
Extract both archives to one folder (I usually create ~/bin). You should get two folders:
eclipse and jre1.7.0_09.

Then edit file eclipse/eclipse.ini, add:

```
-vm
../jre1.7.0_09/bin/java
```

below

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

This will make eclipse always use Oracles's java. Eclipse is only tested to run on oracle's java.

Using this method you can make many eclipse installations with only needed tools in each of them.

Comment: Will there be automatic updates this way?

Comment: Yeah, eclipse has a built-in update function. What updates you will get depends on what software repos you will setup inside eclipse (releases, milestones, nightly, etc.) Inside eclipse "Help->Check for updates" checks available updates. Also there is a periodic check for updates. "window-preferences-install/update/automatic updates". List of eclipse update sites: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites
Beware! Do not mix releases! E.g. current release is 4.2 Juno, do not add repos from 4.3 which is in development(unless you really know what you want from it)